# Wordpress- url for localhost wp-admin is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-theming

I am working in a project with wordpress, it was working properly but I think I have changed some setting in wordpress setting-general option.

So now when I type `localhost/wordpress-demo/wp-admin/` then it redirected me to `http://localhost/wordpress-Demo/Home/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fwordpress-Demo%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1` url.

**wordpress-demo** is my root folder that I have created

but it is giving me error like this:

```
Not Found
```

The requested URL /wordpress-Demo/Home/wp-login.php was not found on this server.

I have typed **Home** in somewhere setting.
So can you please give me some suggestion for work it properly and give me the name of url-mapping file name.

Comment: You can access the General settings options by going into your database and changing the values there. It sounds like the siteurl option needs changing/updating. PS. note the uppercase and lowercase difference you have there!

Comment: Did you try searching for the "Home" pattern in the whole project dir or in the database ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't get to your admin page then you will have to use a database tool to check this.

In a database tool (phpMyAdmin will work) enter this:

```
select * from wp_options where option_name='siteurl' or option_name='home';
```

These are the 2 places that WordPress stores your URL. See if either of them have /home/ in it. If so, correct it and it should fix the problem.

Cheers!

=C=

Comment: yeah. I have changed option_value from  http://localhost/wordpress-Demo/Home to http://localhost/wordpress-Demo/  but its not working its giving some error when I reload page with  http://localhost/wordpress-Demo/ url.

Comment: 1: What error is it giving you and 2: Did you clear your cache or try it in a different browser?

Answer (score 1):

Login in phpmyadmin > wp_options > edit the value for site_url and home_url to your site;

This occur needs to be changed when you're migrating. If still not working try renaming your .htaccess in root directory.